# user relationship table - avoiding duplicates

Tags: mysql

Consider this table:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|               relationships                             |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| id | user_id_1  |  user_id_2   |  status_1  |  status_2 |
+----+------------+--------------+------------------------+
|    |            |              |            |           |
|    |            |              |            |           |
|    |            |              |            |           |
|    |            |              |            |           |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to constrain, user_id_1 and user_id_2
I don't want duplicates like:

```
user_id_1 = 1 and user_id_2 = 2
user_id_1 = 2 and user_id_2 = 1
```

These two are essentially same for my application.

My strategy to avoid duplication is to order user_id before inserting it, and always put smaller one in user_id_1 and bigger id in user_id_2 thus effectively avoiding the original problem.

But is there a better, cleaner way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Maybe a trigger could be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you store users in the same column over separate rows, you can take advantage of the PRIMARY KEY to enforce uniqueness:

```
CREATE TABLE relationships (
  rel_id INT,
  user_id INT,
  status INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (rel_id, user_id)
);
```

It doesn't matter what order you enter the users into this table.

```
INSERT INTO relationships (rel_id, user_id) VALUES (1234, 1), (1234, 2);
```

Is just the same as:

```
INSERT INTO relationships (rel_id, user_id) VALUES (1234, 2), (1234, 1);
```

Because they end up on separate rows. And they end up getting ordered automatically, because those columns are part of the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you would implement this as follows:

```
SQL> create table t1 (a integer,b integer);

Table created.

SQL> create unique index ck_t1_ab on t1(least(a,b),greatest(a,b));

Index created.

SQL>
insert into t1 (a,b) values (1,2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t1 (a,b) values (2,1);
insert into t1 (a,b) values (2,1)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SIMON.CK_T1_AB) violated
```

Sadly, I quickly tested this in MySQL and it does not seem to support it. I would not recommend misusing the PRIMARY KEY of your table but to implement CHECK constraints like this:

```
alter table t1 add constraint uq_t1_ab unique(a,b);
alter table t1 add constraint uq_t1_ba unique(b,a);
```

Then, your workaround (sorting the values before entering) should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a `UNIQUE` constraint

```sql
ALTER TABLE relationships ADD UNIQUE(user_id_1, user_id_2);
```

a possible solution is to reorder user ids transparently while inserting by using a `BEFORE` trigger

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bi_relationships
BEFORE INSERT ON relationships
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE _least, _greatest INT;
  SET _least    = LEAST(NEW.user_id_1, NEW.user_id_2),
      _greatest = GREATEST(NEW.user_id_2, NEW.user_id_1);
  SET NEW.user_id_1 = _least,
      NEW.user_id_2 = _greatest;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64e41/1)** demo. *Try to uncomment the last `INSERT` in schema pane and click `Build Schema`. It will prevent the insertion of duplicate.*

Comment: @salivan Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?